# Find duplicates in table 2 and return back the record based on the id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to make a query to remove the record in table 1 based on the duplicate records found in table 2. id is the common link between these two tables. The Database is oracle. I am new in writing up queries and the below is the query i came up with so far which is not working out. Can anyone please suggest?

I am actually trying to delete record based on the id in table 1 on a condition when there are duplicate records in table 2 for that id as well as one more column? Below is the error message i am getting, am really not sure if query is accurate either or need to re write the whole query itself?

"invalid sql statement" - ORA-00900

```
    DELETE TABLE AS m WHERE m.id IN 
   (SELECT id from table2 t WHERE ROWID > 
(SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM table2 r WHERE t.column2 = r.column2);
```

Comment: `DELETE tab  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id from table2 t WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM table2 r WHERE t.column2 = r.column2));`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.   You description is lacking details.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I just tried the query but no luck :(

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just added more description above hope that helps to understand my issue? I am really even not sure if my approach to write this query is correct on the results which i am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following one(use only `tab` as *the table* in the statement) :

```
create table tab ( id int, val int );
insert into tab values(1 ,331);
insert into tab values(1 ,332);
insert into tab values(2 ,333);
insert into tab values(2 ,333);

select * from tab;

ID  VAL
1   331
1   332
2   333
2   333

delete tab a
 where
   rowid >
       (select min(rowid)
          from tab b
         where b.id=a.id
         group by b.id);      
select * from tab;      

ID  VAL
1   331
2   333
```

[***sqlfiddle demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9d5f3/3)

*As a side note : `table` is a reserved keyword in Oracle and may not be a table name, `"table"` may be used alternatively.*

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I see your solution seems to be for one single table. I am actually trying to delete the id in table 1 where in table 2 that id has duplicate records. Hope this helps?

Comment: @Sam then, Lukasz's suggestion is what you want. Just replace `delete tab` with `delete table1` and column `user_id` with `id`

Comment: seems like Lukasz's suggestion worked! Hmm not sure how did i miss that earlier may was exhausted trying lot of stuff lol.. But thank you so much appreciate your all help!

Answer (score 0):

You would find the duplicates somehow.  This is a little unclear, but perhaps:

```
select t2.column2, count(*)
from table2 t2
group by t2.column2
having count(*) >= 2;
```

You can then put this into the `delete`:

```
delete from m
    where m.id in (select t2.column2
                   from table2 t2
                   group by t2.column2
                   having count(*) >= 2
                  );
```